# Overleaf Premium, worth it?

Tags: overleaf

I have always used Word or Pages for my papers and projects, but when reaching the part to add the equation, charts or graphs there is always a caos trying to fit correctly everything from stata, r, or python. I found Overleaf and I love it, however, I'm curious on the premium subscription, if it worths the 80dls or so, what do you think, in your experience does it worth it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you considered installing a full, totally free TeX distribution on your own computer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as clearly opinion based. There will be some who find it useful and worth the money and some who don't, and many who don't use it at all.

Comment: I have only a free subscription. I find it a  gorgeous product. They are a serious firm with a great staff. The Help Center is very efficient, first of all. You could ask them if there are some promotion offers, to try it for a year spending a little less, and then decide.

Comment: The main benefit of paying is if you are using the collaborative tools - those are limited if you have a free account. So it will largely depend on what workflow you need to use.